# How to insert a new row in a datatable?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two table A and B.
Table A is like:

```
Date           | Value
1/9/2013 13:30 |   1
1/9/2013 13:31 |   2
1/9/2013 13:32 |   2.1
1/9/2013 13:33 |   1.6
1/9/2013 13:34 |   1.7
1/9/2013 13:35 |   1.9
1/9/2013 13:36 |   5.6
1/9/2013 13:37 |   1.6
1/9/2013 13:38 |   1.64
1/9/2013 13:39 |   1.36
```

And table B is like:

```
1/9/2013 13:33 |   1.7
1/9/2013 13:37 |   1.6
1/9/2013 13:38 |   1.8
```

I want to have a table C which will have all entries of B, but if there is not entry at 13:30 for example the value is null. So Table C is like:

```
 Date           | Value
1/9/2013 13:30 |   null
1/9/2013 13:31 |   null
1/9/2013 13:32 |   null
1/9/2013 13:33 |   1.7
1/9/2013 13:34 |   null
1/9/2013 13:35 |   null
1/9/2013 13:36 |   null
1/9/2013 13:37 |   1.6
1/9/2013 13:38 |   1.8
1/9/2013 13:39 |   null
```

I know that one can do that with a join and linq , do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try following `LEFT JOIN` query:

```
from a in dtA.AsEnumerable()
join b in dtB.AsEnumerable() on a.Field<DateTime>("Date") equals b.Field<DateTime>("Date") into joinedB
from b in joinedB.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    Date = a.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
    Value = b != null ? b.Field<DateTime>("Value") : null
}
```